# How to specify a color using Scalar class

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I do not know how to specifiy a color using Scalar class in the below posted method?

```
Features2d.drawKeypoints(mKeyPoints_0, mKeyPoints_0, outImage, Scalar color, Features2d.DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: @MuertoExcobito because opencv has c++ Api as well

Comment: OpenCV also has python bindings, but since your example code is in java(?), it probably doesn't make sense to tag it as C++.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usage of `Scalar` to specify color, depends on the `Mat` type. Attempting to store/draw `Red` color on a grayscale `Mat` will fail.

- Type `CV_8UC1`- grayscale image

  ```
  //8 bits per pixel and so range of [0:255]. 
  Scalar color = new Scalar( 255 )
  //For type: 16UC1, range of [0:65535]. For 32FC1 range is [0.0f:1.0f]
  ```
- Type `CV_8UC3` - 3 channel color image

  ```
  // BLUE: color ordering as BGR
  Scalar color = new Scalar( 255, 0, 0 )
  ```
- Type `CV_8UC4` - color image with transparency

  ```
  //Transparent GREEN: BGRA with alpha range - [0 : 255]
  Scalar color = new Scalar( 0, 255, 0, 128 )
  ```

In the question, the first parameter to `drawKeyPoints` should be your source image(`Mat`) and not keypoints. The code would have compiled because `MatOfKeyPoint` is derived from `Mat`

Comment: i'm new to OpenCV, and I'm so confused that since color = new Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ) means Blue, when I try out with mMat.setTo(color);, it shows a Red color mat, why is it so?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to check out the Java API (http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/core/Scalar.html)

```
Scalar colour = new Scalar(B,G,R);
```

Where B,G,R are doubles, one for each colour channel.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method below to convert ARGB to Scalar

```
public static Scalar argbtoScalar(int r, int g, int b, int a) {
    Scalar s = new Scalar(b, g, r, a);
    return s;
}
```

`a` stands for `Alpha` which specifies the `transparency`.